# Angular and ASP.NET Core to Develop Application for Financial Institute

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Why Angular and ASP.NET Core not recommended as base technologies for Financial Institutes like banks, Stock Exchanges or like?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion platform, we do Q&A, so I'm afraid this is way to broad for our format.

Comment: I have changed it to question instead of a discussion. Hope it is acceptable now.

Comment: I cannot really make out what your specific question is. Half of you post is an unfounded and unsourced claim, the other half *might* be a question, but it's hard to tell because it has grammar errors. Maybe concentrate on the question part. Try to end one sentence with a question mark to make sure we get what you want to ask. Make sure we have all the information you have.

Comment: The basic premise of your question is false. Financial Institutions do use Angular and ASP.NET mostly  traditional but also Core. The increased popularity of Cloud and container technologies is likely to increase the use of .NET Core because of its suitability for containerizing ASP.NET applications.

Comment: @Andrew we encountered counter argument from different institutes, there are not interested to consider OSS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because of sensitive information held by financial institutions(Like Account's number and CC number).

But they can be protected if you follow standards like PCI DSS ones, like not sending the whole Credit card, account or SSN numbers, but just last 4 digits to the front-end, enforce requests to be sent over HTTPS, add CORS, scan you application against OWASP vulnerabilities, you can use [Microsoft Sonar](https://webhint.io/scanner/) tool for that.

Hope you'll find this useful.